# How to group the array by using array value, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, group-by

Here I am trying to fetch the income of a seller, but the problem is that I am unable to group the duplicate the array value into one.

**Logic Function.**

```
function getMonthlyIncomeOfSellerById($sellerId)
{
    $data = array();
    $ddd = array();
    $query = "SELECT date_format(created_at,'%M'), product_id,sell_discount,SUM(sell_quantity) FROM sellers_sells WHERE seller_id=? AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) GROUP BY date_format(created_at,'%M'),seller_id,product_id ORDER BY created_at";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$sellerId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($monthName,$productId,$sellDiscount,$sellQuantity);
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $d['monthName'] = $monthName;
        $d['productId'] = $productId;
        $d['sellDiscount'] = $sellDiscount;
        $d['sellQuantity'] = $sellQuantity;
        array_push($data, $d);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $netProfit = 0;
    $maxProfit = 0;
    foreach ($data as $dt)
    {
        $product = $this->getProductById($dt['productId']);
        $product['productPrice'] = ($product['productPrice']/100)*$dt['sellDiscount'];
        if ($product['productName']==='PRODUCT NAME' && $product['productBrand']==='PRODUCT BRAND' && $product['productSize']==='50ML')
        {
            $maxPrice = $product['productPrice']*$dt['sellQuantity'];
            $price = ($product['productPrice']-10)*$dt['sellQuantity'];
        }
        else if ($product['productName']==='PRODUCT NAME' && $product['productBrand']==='PRODUCT BRAND' && $product['productSize']==='100ML')
        {
            $maxPrice = $product['productPrice']*$dt['sellQuantity'];
            $price = ($product['productPrice']-15)*$dt['sellQuantity'];
        }
        else if ($product['productName']==='PRODUCT NAME' && $product['productBrand']==='PRODUCT BRAND' && $product['productSize']==='200ML')
        {
            $maxPrice = $product['productPrice']*$dt['sellQuantity'];
            $price = ($product['productPrice']-30)*$dt['sellQuantity'];
        }
        $netProfit = $netProfit+$price;
        $maxProfit = $maxProfit+$maxPrice;
        $dts['monthName'] = $dt['monthName'];
        $dts['netProfit'] = $netProfit;
        $dts['maxProfit'] = $maxProfit;
        array_push($ddd, $dts);
    }
    print_r($ddd);
}
```

Getting the out put with duplicate value.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [monthName] => January
            [netProfit] => 2050
            [maxProfit] => 2800
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [monthName] => March
            [netProfit] => 2214
            [maxProfit] => 3024
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [monthName] => March
            [netProfit] => 4149
            [maxProfit] => 5604
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [monthName] => March
            [netProfit] => 4523
            [maxProfit] => 6148
        )

)
```

But here I want to group it with the month, and add all the values into one.

Like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [monthName] => January
            [netProfit] => 2050
            [maxProfit] => 2800
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [monthName] => March
            [netProfit] => 10886
            [maxProfit] => 14776
        )
)
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by 'month' by usign the `monthName` as key. If the key doesn't exists, create a new entry with default values. Then, you could add (`+`) the current value from the data.

```
    $monthName = $dt['monthName'];

    if (!isset($ddd[$monthName])) {
        $ddd[$monthName] = [
            'monthName' => $monthName, 
            'netProfit' => 0,
            'maxProfit' => 0,
        ];
    }

    $ddd[$monthName]['netProfit'] += $netProfit;
    $ddd[$monthName]['maxProfit'] += $maxProfit;
```

Instead of

```
    $dts['monthName'] = $dt['monthName'];
    $dts['netProfit'] = $netProfit;
    $dts['maxProfit'] = $maxProfit;
    array_push($ddd, $dts);
```

To remove added keys, you could use :

```
$ddd = array_values($ddd);
```